# Failed to resolve Plugins for module react-native-blob-util and react-native-pdf

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-pdf

I am using expo Version : 46.0.0 and i want to install react-native-pdf but the mention module requires react-native-blob-util after installing both and adding plugins in app.json i am getting error for failed to resolve plugins. Can anyone help me out yrr. I am new to Expo. Thanks in advance!!

In app.json- Inside expo object i am adding following plugins

```
    "plugins": [
      "@config-plugins/react-native-blob-util",
      "@config-plugins/react-native-pdf"
    ],
```

[image]